# How do I use redux to do multiple actions in the saga and track the overall success/fail in the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, graphql

In my `EmailCollection/index.js` file, in an `updateUsersEmail` function, I have the following code:

```
this.props.checkEmail(email)
  .then(() => {
    this.props.redirect();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
  });
```

`checkEmail` and `updateUserEmail` are an **actions** defined as

```
export const updateUserEmail = (userEmail) => {
  return createGraphqlAction(
    {
      query: `
        mutation setLoginEmail($userEmail: String!) {
          setLoginEmail(email: $userEmail) {
            login {
              email
            }
            state
            name
            id
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        userEmail,
      },
    },
    UPDATE_USER_EMAIL,
  );
};

export const checkEmail = (userEmail) => {
  return createGraphqlAction(
    {
      query: `
        query checkEmail($userEmail: String!) {
          checkEmail(email: $userEmail) {
            isEmailTaken
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        userEmail,
      },
    },
    CHECK_IF_EMAIL_IS_TAKEN, <- this is a constant for a string of the same format to prevent any spelling issues
  );
};
```

Finally, in my `checkEmail.js`, I have:

```
import { takeEvery, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { updateUserEmail, CHECK_IF_EMAIL_IS_TAKEN } from './../actions';

export default function* confirmEmailSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(CHECK_IF_EMAIL_IS_TAKEN.SUCCESS, function* (result) {
    const { isEmailTaken } = result.data.checkEmail;
    const { email } = result.variables.userEmail;

    if (isEmailTaken) {
      // TODO: return some error that EmailCollection.js can consume

    } else {
      yield put(updateUserEmail(email)); // this isn't updating, why?
    }
  });
```

Ideally in that the `isEmailTaken` logic above, I'd want to return something that the component can consume which gives info about the nature of the error so I can adjust the UI accordingly.

I'd also like to understand why `yield put(updateUserEmail(email))` isn't causing the user's status to update the in database.

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your first question, maybe dispatching an action attaching some info about the error there? Then a reducer could take care of that and update the state so the component can use it.

Comment: Thanks @newpatriks. I'm a bit rusty on my redux, would you mind proving an example as an answer to help me and anyone who may come across this in the future please? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `isEmailTaken` has returned?  Would a REST-based example help?